# Java custom annotation for performance tracking

Tags: java, performance, annotations

I want to measure performance of various functions in my project. This will be run on multiple threads, so right now I have something like this

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
first();
StatsTracker.putTime("first", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
...
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
second();
StatsTracker.putTime("second", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Where StatsTracker is a static class that simply keeps track of a map of performances.

I am new to writing custom annotations, and a few tutorials I saw online made it a little confusing. What I want in the end is something like this

```
@StartTime("first")
first();
@EndTime("first")
...
@StartTime("second")
second();
@EndTime("second")
```

Then for the start/end time annotations, I want the two annotations to record the current system time and then put that run-time into a map (to record average performance).

Edit: It might be more natural to have something like this before the definition of the functions:

```
@TrackTime("first")
public void first() { ... }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, the first example is not only simpler but faster as many AOP frameworks to support annotations have an overhead.  BTW I would use System.nanoTime() and warm-up the code  i.e. measure the first 10,000 calls separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are just meta-data. They don't do anything.

A framework can get the annotations on methods and classes using reflection to do something with them. This means that, to do what you want to do, you would need to use AOP to find the annotations on the methods and measure the time they spent.

Such frameworks exist (like Jamon combined with Spring beans for example). But writing one yourself will take much more time than doing what you're doing now, and will probably force you to change the way your application is architected in order to use some form of dependency injection. Or you'll have to instrument the byte-code with AspectJ for example.

So my advice would be: don't change anything, or use an dependency injection framework and use an existing product (like jamon for example), or write a custom AOP interceptor to measure the time taken by the methods of the components.

Comment: Ah, okay I didn't realize that. I was associating Java annotations with Python decorators and was hoping that they did something similar :\ Thanks for the advice!